# How to configure ubuntu host as private but virtual machine as public?

Tags: apache, networking, ubuntu-14.04

i trying to setup an apache proxy on VM. I have no issue that create the VM, i have setup the network for the connection between the host and VM through bridge connection. Now both host and VM can be access by the public.

But with client requirement, we are not allow to have the host as public. Hence i need go setup the host as internal network. Which means only the apache VM is allow to be ssh or ftp from outside, the host is not allow to be access from outside. All request will be proxy through apache VM.

Would like to know any export know how to do this ? Attached with the basic request diagram. Looking for the advice and answer. Thanks.

**Info**
Ubuntu 14.04 , Apache2 , KVM

[The basic diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpE3x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I really have stuck at this, what i have succesful setup is host and VM is accessible by public, via bridge connection.

When i try to set it as NAT conenection, the VM will be not accessible.

I have think an alternative way is block all the access port in the host, but host allowed to outbound , but not allowed inbound, but allow inbound from VM.

I hope have an expert help on this. Thanks.